# Swagger - PHP Annotations define object in model

Tags: php, annotations, swagger

I'm using this symfony extension:
https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/index.html.

I defined some response models to ref them later in controller.

In one model I need to defined "details" property as object.
Hot to do it to achive result like this:

```
"id": integer,
"title": string,
"details": {
       "status": "string",
       "time" : "integer"
    }
```

And this is my Model where I have to set my "details" object:

```
class Article
{



/**
 * @var integer|null
 * @Groups({"APIResponse"})
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string|null
 * @Groups({"APIResponse"})
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @var ??
 * @Groups({"APIResponse"})
 */
private $details;

/**
 * @return integer|null
 */
public function getId(): ?string
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getTitle(): ?string
{
    return $this->title;
}
```

}

How to do it?
Thank you.

Comment: The output you've shown us seems like JSON so could not just define `details` as an array and then encode it?

Comment: No, it doesn't work.